# How to use an NPM module on a server that doesn't have NPM

Tags: javascript, npm, jwplayer

I'd like to use the latest version of JW Player on a web server to which I con only upload files (no shell access). In the past (JW Player 5), I just copied a single file to the web server, `jwplayer.js`. Alas, things are not so simple these days. Now you need to install dependencies, use NPM, etc. I have a Linux machine on which I can do this, but I can still only upload files to the production machine (which doesn't have NPM, uses Adobe ColdFusion, and probably runs Windows NT 4.0).

Is there a way to export an NPM module that I haven't created myself (i.e. JW Player) to a machine that doesn't have NPM?

Comment: You can install npm if you have a shell access to the machine no ?

Comment: You could always grab the module folder from the `node_modules` directory and push that up to the server. Is the machine restricted from `npm` because of the way it was set up - like security issues, or what?

Comment: As stated, I don't have shell access to the machine. I think it doesn't have NPM because it's ancient and no one wants to change it. I'm free to put HTML and JavaScript files on the machine but I don't have permission to do anything more.